# Create a new Column in Pandas DataFrame and populate the values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I have the following dataframe:

```
df_dict = {'time':[1,2,3],'a':['a1','a2','a3'],'b':['b1','b2','b3'], 'c':['c1','c2','c3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

df

  time  a   b   c
0   1   a1  b1  c1
1   2   a2  b2  c2
2   3   a3  b3  c3
```

I need to add a new column which takes value from columns a, b , c and become like this:

```
   time   new_column   values
0   1        a           a1
1   2        a           a2
2   3        a           a3
3   1        b           b1
4   2        b           b2
5   3        b           b3
6   1        c           c1
7   2        c           c2
8   3        c           c3
```

Basically, the values in column 'time' is repeated. 
I need help with the **Python** code please. And what is the technical term for this action?
Very much appreciated.

Comment: this looks like pandas [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Try df.melt('time')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.melt`

```
In [3]: df.melt(id_vars='time', value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c'])                                                              
Out[3]: 
   time variable value
0     1        a    a1
1     2        a    a2
2     3        a    a3
3     1        b    b1
4     2        b    b2
5     3        b    b3
6     1        c    c1
7     2        c    c2
8     3        c    c3
```